# I am unable to use to sort a PagingData - Paging3 Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack, android-paging-3

In my project I have successfully implemented Paging3 library. The data is showing in UI through my MembersPagingAdapter class.
What I am unable to do it is to sort the list of members alphabetically as per name/username, Or,
as per registration date(UNIX timestamp).

I am only getting option to filer, and switchMap.

Comment: If the data comes from Room then your SQL query should be able to handle it.

Comment: @cutiko, What if it directly comes from network call.? How to sort them?
Also not saving the data to room, and directly showing it from network - is it a good flow?